# Trigger an event in Microsoft Access when a report is printed from DoCmd OpenReport

Tags: events, ms-access, report

I am trying to run a script on a report which is being run using DoCmd OpenReport. I am not previewing the report but sending it straight to the printer.  It seems that when you do this, none of the events for the report are triggered.  Is there anyway to trigger something like OnLoad when the report prints?

Answer (score 0):

The open event will occur: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211439(office.11).aspx

Comment: This works for forms of course, but I need to know how to get an event to trigger on a report when I print it from a VBA script.  If the report opens in preview mode, events such as onLoad will trigger, but not if the report is printed without viewing the report form.

Comment: @mackeyka The open event applies to reports as well as forms. This is stated in "Applies to" in the link.

Comment: This is true, but my problem is that when the report is printed from a VBA script with the following command:

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acNormal, , stLinkCriteria

the report is not actually being opened on the screen (such as in Print Preview) first and none of the events that would normally occur are being triggered.

Comment: Try it. Put `MsgBox "Hello"` in the open event and run VBA to open it, the message box will popup. Also, I am by no means clear why you want code in the report when you are running from VBA. You can branch to what ever code you want after the print line.

Comment: Tried it. OnOpen works for print preview from VBA but not trigger if report goes directly to printer. The report is very complex, many subforms.  One section will be different depending on whether the report is for Group A or Group B.  The code I want to run will picks subform to print at that location based on which group the report is for.  There is a field on the report which identifies which group the report is for and the code on the report uses this field to determine which subform to print.  The whole database is large and I don’t want another report in there when this one should do.

Comment: The open event would not be suitable for what you want to do. Have you tried changing the subform in the print event of the detail section? Does the subform control content need to change or the data? You may wish to consider the link child and master fields. Reports are very fussy about events, as you have found.

Comment: Very fussy indeed, I can't see why the load event would not run whether I view the report of print it.  Very frustating. I can't get any events to trigger ie. report, header, detail whatever.  No events will trigger.  The portion of the report that changes is all static.

Comment: Can you try with a simple form, in case something is interfering with your code? Just add debug.print to the Print event for the detail, say.

Comment: Made a simple form that just says "Hello World" and the same thing happen.  If I view the report before printing then events fire, but if I just print the report without viewing then none of the various events I set up are triggered.  I am using the work around that lstari suggested for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and solved it by first opening the report hidden:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewReport, , strCriteria, acHidden
```

Then sending it to printer and closing the report.

Comment: A version of this is working for me.  Changed DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, **acNormal**, , stLinkCriteria to DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, **acViewReport**, , stLinkCriteria.  could not use acHidden though because it printed a different open form instead of the report that was just opened.  So the report flashes on the screen but the users will just have to live with that for a while until I can figure out why it prints the wrong thing.